# getting logcat error as cannot be casted

Tags: android, logcat

I want to generate a listview from sqlite database but the 
LOGCAT shows error.
What does this below error mean?

```
09-23 12:01:20.354: E/AndroidRuntime(3682): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abhishekp.listproduct/com.abhishekp.listproduct.List}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
```

Comment: It means you're trying to cast from a `TextView` to a `ListView`. You'd need to show us some code to figure out where it's happening and how to fix it

Comment: Post the respective piece of code dude

Comment: without code nobody can help you dude

Comment: Just try to clean your project.. It should work fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Happen only because of..two possibilities.

1) If you are using TextView in xml file...

and try to initialize it with.

```
TextView tv=(ListView)findViewbyId(R.id.textView);
```

and if it is right then change it with

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewbyId(R.id.textView);
```

2) May be you are trying to put id of listView instead of text view.

like

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewbyId(R.id.listView);
```

if it is then should change

```
TextView tv=(TextView )findViewbyId(R.id.textView );
```

And if it is all good then try to clean your project and rebuild it...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

From your logcat its clearly showing that you are trying to cast your `TextView` in `ListView`. Check you may have declared your `TextView` i.e.

```
   TextView tv=(ListView)findViewbyId(R.id.textView);
```

or may be you are referring the id of your `ListView` in your java file.

```
    TextView tv=(ListView)findViewbyId(R.id.listView); //id defined is of listview
```

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse tends to mess up your resources every now and then. This leads to some odd behavior such as strings and images being swapped all over your app, and more commonly classCastException(s), which happen when Eclipse switches your Views' ids around.

Just clean your project.It will work fine.